# Create a listview for navigation pulled from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm new to Asp.net and I'm currently trying to convert an html page to an asp.net website. The navigation works well with the css and used an unordered list to populate.

```
<ul class="menu" id="responsive">
<li><a href="General.aspx" runat="server" id="currentGeneral"><i class="home"></i> Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="Calendarized.aspx" runat="server" id="currentCalendarized" ><i class="calendar"></i> Calendar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now that i'm moving to asp.net and depending on who is logged in, the navigation will change.

In Site.Master I created

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewMenu" runat="server">

<LayoutTemplate>
    <ul class="menu" id="responsive" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="menuContainer" runat="server" />
    </ul>
</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
    <li><a href="<%#Eval ("href") %>" runat="server" id="<%#Eval ("id") %>"><i class="<%#Eval ("class") %>"></i><%#Eval ("text") %></a></li>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

I then Created a stored proc that will pull that table I need depending on the user.

```
ID    href          id              class  text
1     general.aspx  currentGeneral  home   overview
```

Then in the Site.Master.cs page I created a class to populate the menu on page_PreRender

```
    void PopulateMenu()
    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        da.AddParameter("ID", ID, DataAccess.SQLDataType.SQLInteger, 4);
        SiteMenu = da.runSPDataSet("Portal_MenuCreate");
        ListViewMenu.DataSource = SiteMenu;
        ListViewMenu.DataBind();
    }
```

I thought this would work but im getting the following

```
Parser Error: The server tag is not well formed. 
<li><a href="<%#Eval ("href") %>" runat="server" id="<%#Eval ("id") %>"><i class="<%#Eval ("class") %>"></i><%#Eval ("text") %></a></li>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, maybe this is not the best way to do this? Thanks for any insight.

Edited---
The reason for id-currentGeneral and runat"server" is because with the template I need to set the ID to current if its the current page (changes the tab color)

```
switch (pageName)
        {
            case "General.aspx":
                currentGeneral.Attributes["class"] = "active";
                break;
            case "Calendarized.aspx":
                currentCalendarized.Attributes["class"] = "active";
                break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have `id="<%#Eval ('id') %>"` in `runat="server"`

```
<li><a href='<%#Eval ("href") %>' runat="server" id="HyperLink1">
   <i class='<%#Eval ("class") %>'></i><%#Eval ("text") %></a></li>
```

You won't even need `runat="server"` and `id`, if you are not accessing that hyperlink at server side. If so, remove both to make your code clean -

```
<li><a href='<%#Eval ("href") %>' class='<%#Eval ("id") %>'>
   <i class='<%#Eval ("class") %>'></i><%#Eval ("text") %></a></li>
```

**FYI:** If you need css style, use `class` rather than `id`

Comment: The ID won't work like a normal control's ID anyway, since its in the ItemTemplate, so +1 for skipping it.

Comment: Ah ok, then I will have to change how I use ID. I edited my post but the reason for id-currentGeneral and runat"server" is because with the template I need to set the ID to current if its the current page (changes the tab color).

Comment: Ok I understand the change. Thank you for clarifying. I do get a new error. An item placeholder must be specified on ListView 'ListViewMenu'. Specify an item placeholder by setting a control's ID property to "itemPlaceholder". The item placeholder control must also specify runat="server". For my ListViewMenu.Databind();

Comment: Assign `menuContainer` to `ItemPlaceHoldId` property like this - `<asp:ListView ... ItemPlaceholderID="menuContainer">...`

Comment: Thanks Win! I really do appreciate it. Now to fix the Id style.

Comment: I know its pretty ugly but do you know a way to add back the id="current" when they are on a current page if I cant use runat server?

Comment: It is different from original question. Could you please create a new question?

Comment: Sorry Win. Created a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959148/set-id-using-listview-without-runat-server

Answer (score -1):

try using single quotation marks so your double quotations are recognized properly

```
<li><a href="<%#Eval ('href') %>" runat="server" id="<%#Eval ('id') %>"><i class="<%#Eval ('class') %>"></i><%#Eval ('text') %></a></li>
```

Comment: I tried that but on <%#Eval ('class') %> and <%#Eval ('text') %> says "Too many characters in character literal."

Comment: `Eval ('href')` is a C# expression. It's a method named `Eval` wich expects a string. If you pass `'href'` you are passing an invalid char reference (since single quotation is for chars and chars consists in a single character)