# How to assign dynamic css class to HyperLink located inside ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Kinda of confusing title.

This is my old navigation

```
<li><a href="General.aspx" runat="server" id="currentGeneral"><i class="home"></i> Overview</a></li>
```

The i class sets an icon next to the navigation tab.

On the Site.Master.CS I checked what the current page was and would set it to active with the code below.

```
currentGeneral.Attributes["class"] = "active";
```

So I changed the navigation to a listview populated by a database.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewMenu" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="menuContainer">

<LayoutTemplate>
    <ul class="menu" id="responsive" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="menuContainer" runat="server" />
    </ul>
</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<li><a href='<%#Eval ("href") %>' class='<%#Eval ("id") %>'> <i class='<%#Eval ("class") %>'></i><%#Eval ("text") %></a></li>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

But now that I am using listview, the currentGeneral id does not exist and I cant set it to active.

I was trying to think what the best way to get this to work is. Anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access individual item inside of `ListView` while binding, you might want a different approach using [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) event.

Please make sure to cast DataItem to appropiate object. For example, [DataRowView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx)

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewMenu" runat="server" 
    OnItemDataBound="ListViewMenu_ItemDataBound"
    ItemPlaceholderID="menuContainer">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul class="menu" id="responsive" runat="server">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="menuContainer" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" >
               <i class='<%#Eval ("class") %>'></i><%#Eval ("text") %>
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateMenu();
    }
}

protected void ListViewMenu_ItemDataBound(
    object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var rowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

        var hyperLink = e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HyperLink;
        hyperLink.NavigateUrl = rowView["href"].ToString();
        hyperLink.CssClass = rowView["menu"].ToString();

        if (Request.Path.ToLower().Contains(rowView["href"].ToString()))
            hyperLink.CssClass += " active";
    }
}
void PopulateMenu()
{
    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
    da.AddParameter("ID", ID, DataAccess.SQLDataType.SQLInteger, 4);
    SiteMenu = da.runSPDataSet("Portal_MenuCreate");
    ListViewMenu.DataSource = SiteMenu;
    ListViewMenu.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: The reason I was pulling the navigation from the database was due to a user could have a different nav. Some users don't have calendarized.aspx so my stored proc populates it depending on the user. SO how would you count for that by setting the menu in the page load?

Comment: Just replace `collection` with your datasource. It should work. (Note I created it so that I can test it without database).

Comment: Oh sorry. Its been a long day, I just totally overlooked that with out paying attention.

Comment: Would I need to change var menu = e.Item.DataItem as DataView; ? I replaced the whole var collection = new List<Menu> code for the dataaccess code. Because I would get an error that hyperLink.NavigateUrl = menu.Href; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Yes I think your data item is DataView. Uncomment and make a break point at `var menu = e.Item.DataItem as DataView;` and look at the type of `e.Item.DataItem`.

Comment: I uncomment out the e.item.dataitem as dataview. I then set public class Menu to public class Dataview (Or else menu.href and menu.class didn't work).  Set the break point. It looks like var menu stays at null. and then it gets an error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) at hyperlink.navigateURL = menu.Href;

Comment: I updated answer. Here is an example of casting DataItem to DataRowView. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the microsoft doc. I have a lot to read up on to get my head around this. With your updated code I had to change hyperLink.CssClass = rowView["class"].ToString(); to hyperLink.CssClass = rowView["id"].ToString(); Which now works great. But its back to where the tab is not set to active if its the current page. This is the link it creates. <a id="ListViewMenu_HyperLink1_0" class="currentGeneral"href="GeneralInfo.aspx"><i class='home'></i> Overview</a> This is how it should look <a href="GeneralInfo.aspx" id="currentGeneral" class="active"><i class="home"></i> Overview</a>

Comment: I fixed it by doing the following.  if (Request.Url.ToString().Split('/').Last().Contains(rowView["href"].ToString())) hyperLink.CssClass += " active";

Comment: Thanks again Win. I really do appreciate it. I need to buy you a beer.